# How to determine if a WebView is zoomed out all the way

Tags: android, webview, scroll, zooming

I'm looking for a way to detect whether or not a WebView is zoomed out fully.  I know you can get a boolean return value from ZoomOut(), but that will perform the zoom out.  I just want to simply know whether or not it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use my custom `WebView` class.

Get `WebView`'s view height and inner html web page's `contentHeight`.

Calculate `defaultScale = WebView.getHeight() / WebView.getContentHeight();` and `currentScale = WebView.getScale()`.

If `defaultScale` < `currentScale` it's zoomed.

```
public class NoZoomControllWebView extends WebView {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean isZoomed () {
        boolean result = false;

        int contentHeight = getContentHeight();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 ) {
            float scale = getScale();
            int temp = (int)(((float)viewHeight / (float)contentHeight) * 100);

            if (temp < (int)(scale * 100)) {
                result = true;
            }
        } else {
            float scale = getScale();
            int temp = (int)(((float)viewHeight / (float)contentHeight) * 100);

            if (temp < (int)(scale * 100)) {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`getScaled()`
is deprecated you should use `onScaleChanged`
on your WebViewClient instead

You can use it like this:

```
            private boolean zoomed = false, firstRun = true;

            @Override
            public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale,
                    float newScale) {
                if (firstRun) {
                    initScale = newScale;
                    firstRun=false;
                    zoomed = false;
                }
                else {
                    if (newScale>oldScale) {
                        zoomed = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (newScale<initScale) {
                            zoomed = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
            }
```

if we presume the WebView is zoomed max out from the start.

Comment: This is not 100% reliable as sometimes zooming out (either double tapping or by pinch) can end up with zoomed being set to true (it's a little oversensitive basically) but this is still the best solution on this page and fine for my use case.

Clearing the flags on page start+finished is recommended though otherwise you can be left with the wrong state.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class which extends WebView and override the zoomOut() method. Every time the user zooms out, call super.zoomOut(). Save what is returned to a boolean variable with class scope so it can be persisted with onSaveInstanceState() or in SharedPreferences if needed.

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    // WebViews are generally zoomed out all the way when first created so set defaults
    private boolean lastZoomInResult = true;
    private boolean lastZoomOutResult = false;

    @Override
    public boolean zoomIn() {
        lastZoomInResult = super.zoomIn();
        return lastZoomInResult;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoomOut() {
        lastZoomOutResult = super.zoomOut();
        return lastZoomOutResult;
    }
```

**EDIT:** In response to this not working for pinch zoom... you are quite correct and ultimately Cristian's answer holds true.

I hooked my phone up via USB to my PC with DDMS. I see the following when I pinch zoom my Webview...

```
01-06 03:18:19.052: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(92): Layer::setBuffers(this=0x849ac0), pid=23072, w=1, h=1
01-06 03:18:19.052: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(92): Layer::setBuffers(this=0x849ac0), pid=23072, w=1, h=1
01-06 03:18:19.082: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(92): Layer::requestBuffer(this=0x849ac0), index=0, pid=23072, w=480, h=74 success
01-06 03:18:19.832: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(92): Layer::setBuffers(this=0x738378), pid=23072, w=1, h=1
01-06 03:18:19.832: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(92): Layer::setBuffers(this=0x738378), pid=23072, w=1, h=1
01-06 03:18:19.852: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(92): Layer::requestBuffer(this=0x738378), index=0, pid=23072, w=480, h=74 success
```

In short, it isn't WebView which is zooming. What's actually happening is a digital zoom of the graphics display - the WebView content stays exactly the same size regardless of a zoom in or out but it's being digitally 'magnified' or 'shrunk' like the digital zoom on a digital camera.

I don't fully understand what SurfaceFlinger is but from a quick Google search, we're talking 'device driver' stuff here.

The only thing that changes in those SurfaceFlinger log messages are the hex value for 'this=' and they bear no relevance to the zoom state. The above is logging two pinch attempts when the screen was fully zoomed out.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea but those methods are only called when a user presses a zoom in and zoom out button.  They are not called if they pinch zoom.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: See my answer below the code I originally posted (from the point marked 'EDIT:').

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I figured out a crude way to pull it off that is working so far (posted as an answer).  Thanks again though!

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: No problem - it was an interesting exercise and taught me something about how views zoom. The fun is always in the learning. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to see what else anyone might come up with but I was able to accomplish this through javascript.  It's frustrating because I can see the values needed to easily determine this in the source code of the WebView but they are private with no getters...

Anyhow the solution I have so far is add a JavaScriptInterface which allows me to get the document.body.scrollWidth value for the page.  This provides me with the scrollable width, which for some reason is not available even though there is a getContentHeight() method.  Using this, I can calculate whether or not it is fully zoomed out.

Here is the method the javascript interface calls:

```
public void checkIfZoomedOut(int scrollWidth){
   int zoomedOutThreshold = 5; // If you want to include "nearly zoomed out"
   if( Math.abs(Math.ceil(mWebView.getScale() * scrollWidth) - mWebView.getWidth()) <= zoomedOutThreshold){
       // It is zoomed out
   } else {
       // It is zoomed in
   }
```

}

The scrollWidth is document.body.scrollWidth

**Edit:**  After further experimenting I found protected methods called computeHorizontalScrollRange() and computeHorizontalScrollExtent() that can be called if you subclass the WebView.  You can use them to determine if horizontal scrolling is active/needed.  However, some webpages can be fully zoomed out (the WebView won't let you zoom out any further) and still have a horizontal scrollbar, such as webpages with  text.  So it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !webView.zoomOut () ){
   // couldn't zoom out because the zoom out did nothing :(
   // THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT TO KNOW!
} else{
    webView.zoomIn(); // restore
}
```

> > I just want to simply know whether or not it can.

There's no way to do so.

Comment: If that is the only way to do it, is there a way to make it happen instantly (not animated) so it doesn't appear to zoom out and zoom in to the user?