# Is there anyway to get the scrollable width or getContentWidth?

Tags: android, width, scroll

This is driving me a little crazy because it seems like a fairly straight forward thing.  The WebView has a method called getContentHeight(), but it does not have getContentWidth().

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610715/how-to-determine-if-a-webview-is-zoomed-out-all-the-way), which is related but I also wanted to ask this and it seemed it is slightly different so I created a separate question.

I want to figure out some way to get the total width of the scrollable content.  This value is obviously known because it is used to determine the size of a horizontal scrollbar but why is there no public access to this value?  Is there any way to get this value or make these calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there are some protected methods that you can call if you subclass the view.  These return some values you can use to figure this out.

computeVerticalScrollExtent()

computeVerticalScrollRange()

computeVerticalScrollOffset()

Comment: You could've explained better how to use those values.

Answer (score 0):

capturePicture().getWidth()

And i dont have the answer to the question WHY getContentWidth() function is not there :)